# Why are my python programs not using a full core?

Tags: python, windows, load, cpu, cpu-usage

I understand python only runs on one core aside from using something like multiprocessing. When I use python however, the core it's using only gets as high as 66%, and averages about 50%. It's like there's a cap. I was reading from files when I discovered it, so I changed it to this to make sure it wasn't the I/O:

```
count = 0
while count <= 10000000000:
    count +=1
```

This should be pure python so nothing should stop it from using a full core, right? Yet right now it says one core is at 46% and the rest are about 1%. The RAM is 41%. The power usage in the task bar (Windows 10) says the python power usage is very high, but the cpu is not really moving. I've searched the internet and couldn't find anythong else like this. What can I do to optimize this? I ran a cpuz benchmark and that had the cores hitting 100%, but ran a python benchmark (that I found on github) and again only got to around 40% for one core. If it helps, here's the one I used:

```
start_benchmark = 10000 # change this if you like (sample: 1000, 5000, etc)
start_benchmark = int(start_benchmark)

repeat_benchmark = 10 # attemps, change this if you like (sample: 3, 5, etc)
repeat_benchmark = int(repeat_benchmark)

average_benchmark = 0

for a in range(0,repeat_benchmark):

  start = time.time()

  for i in range(0,start_benchmark):
    for x in range(1,1000):
      3.141592 * 2**x
    for x in range(1,10000):
      float(x) / 3.141592
    for x in range(1,10000):
      float(3.141592) / x

  end = time.time()
  duration = (end - start)
  duration = round(duration, 3)
  average_benchmark += duration
  print('Time: ' + str(duration) + 's')

average_benchmark = round(average_benchmark / repeat_benchmark, 3)
print('Average (from 10 repeats): ' + str(average_benchmark) + 's')
```

I also reinstalled python 3.11 with no change. Anyone have any clue how to get python running to it's full potential? I'm running AMD Ryzen 7 5700G with an ASRock 520M-HDV if that helps diagnose anything.

Comment: Do trivial loops in other languages also display this way?  Like in C, `while(1){}` or using a counter if you want it to end on its own without having to control-c.  Or in a shell like bash, `while true; do true; done`  (`true` is a shell builtin, so it shouldn't be spawning new processes.)  But yeah, that trivial counted loop in Python should max out one core, and make the Windows load average show as 1/N where N is the number of logical cores in your system.  (And if it's not getting scheduled to different cores, yes, one core should be at 100%).  Works as expected on my Linux desktop.

Comment: How many cores does it show? Can you show a screenshot?

Comment: I don't know how to share a screenshot. But I have Xmeters showing each core on my task bar and running the while true loop in Git Bash the core count goes "10% 3% 4% 3% 48% 3% 1% 4%". I'm assuming the loop is running on the one that says 48, but I don't know why it doesn't say 100. I guess bash does that too, but like I said before, the cpuZ benchmark runs them at 100%